# Does the armature disappear during movie rendering?

Tags: rendering, armature

I'm just curious but does the armature show up during the final render when I activate render animation. Because I only want the model's physical appearance to appear not the bones. It would be nice not having to manually make them disappear.[image]

Comment: Why don't you try to render 1 frame to find out? :)

Comment: Usually on this site we are asking people when they say "it doesn't work", what have you tried so far or what are you struggling with. So I have to ask: did you make any effort to find it out by yourself? Like the simplest thing, hitting the F12 button to render a single frame as Harry suggested?

Answer (score 3):

Lol, no. Armatures are not visible during renders. Neither are empties, cameras, or annotations.

Comment: I'm curious though, is it possible to make them show up in the render?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie No, it's not. You would have to model a placeholder object. And not mentioned in the question: the light sources (not the emitted light, I mean the objects themselves) can be made visible if you enable _Visibility_ > _Ray Visibility_ > _Camera_. However  _Point_ and _Area_ lights will be visible no matter which angle (unless the _Area_ is not completely flat from the camera's point of view), while the _Sun_ will only be visible if pointing towards the camera's field of view and the _Spot_ only if the camera'S FOV lies within the cone of light emitted by the spot.

Comment: thanks for sharing Gordon!

Comment: @Harry McKenzie You can make it visible if you use View > Viewport Render Animation

Comment: @moonboots Although it's not really showing up in the render, it's just showing up as overlays in the viewport which you are using instead of the real render... so it depends on what you count in as "render"... and if you switch to rendered view and render the viewport it does not really work with _Cycles_, and if you want to fake it to make it look like a "real" _Eevee_ rendering and switch off the _Overlays_ then those objects are invisible as well.